# Why would php://input truncate?

Tags: php, upload

I have the line `$input = fopen( 'php://input', 'r' );` in my code for uploads.

When the file is done uploading, I check against `$_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH']` to see everything was sent as expected. Recently the `CONTENT_LENGTH` and the size of my upload file started to not match randomly ( About once every 20 minutes with people uploading very frequently ).

I logged and saved the mismatches and found that some files were unable to be opened, while some downloaded and were cut off. One I opened in Photoshop even warned that the document was damaged.

Is there any server config I should be looking for that may have been changed?

I tried replicating by shutting browser tabs and things of that nature but still would not replicate the error.

We are uploading via an AJAX POST. The `POST` body is the upload source.

Comment: Uploads are a tempermental thing to work with, how are you saving your files? Writing them to a database? or storing the file in a folder and referencing the path within the database/

Comment: The bad copies are being stored in a folder, I log the location and check them

Comment: Without understanding the code that actually makes the POST request to your server, this will be impossible to figure out. How is the data sent? Flash, Javascript, HTML Form, etc..? I've encountered issues like this before, but it was usually a math error when building the chunks and sending it to STDIN.

Comment: It's done via an AJAX post

Comment: How large are the files?

Comment: Anywhere from like 200k to a few meg.

Comment: In most cases, by the time you do `fopen('php://input')`, the whole request has already been handled, so this might be related to your web server itself.

Comment: @Jack Where would I even check to see something like that going wrong? If it were throwing notices or other errors I would have picked it up in our logs. They go straight to our internal tool where I see the fails happening.

Comment: I'm not sure, typically web servers would respond with a 4xx response if the sent body is less than advertised in the headers.

Comment: If the response were one of those codes, my code wouldn't make it that far I believe

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why would stream\_copy\_to\_stream not return expected value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26556244/why-would-stream-copy-to-stream-not-return-expected-value)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like a load/networking issue. Either there is a latency issue/timeout issue where the users are trying to upload and your server is not responding.

Usually it's not the AJAX to blame, rather the server (maybe not even PHP) . I think there are drops in some places of the packets coming to the server. It can be limitation in the datacenter (Ex. bandwith cap.) or limitation on the server itself.

We optimize our server using the following configuration. This should work on any linux distro:

Edit `/etc/sysctl.conf` file. Add the following lines in the end:

```
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem= 10240 87380 12582912
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem= 10240 87380 12582912
net.core.rmem_max=12582912
net.core.wmem_max=12582912
net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog=100000
```

You can use the following manual from IBM to better understand how to tune up your linux:
http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redpapers/pdfs/redp4285.pdf

Also,

I would log the client's browser version. It might be that the format sent to your server depends on the AJAX is different from one browser to the other. Since you didn't specify the AJAX code it's hard to assume what's the AJAX doing to upload the files.

Comment: Thanks! In the office tomorrow so I'll be able to better check out what these config settings mean. The issue is in all the browsers. I doubt it's the AJAX since it worked flawless for years. We made server changes, but nothing that should impact an upload... they were a whole set of different servers than the ones giving a problem. It was very strange, and I doubt coincidental, timing.

Comment: Sorry for not getting back! The response was that it may fix this issue, or it may fix this issue and break our site, so our devops was worried about making that change.

Answer (score -3):

There is a `post_max_size` and an `upload_max_filesize` directive in php.ini, compare the values against the size of your truncated files to see whether that's the reason.

Comment: It wouldn't get that far if that were the case and I can easily upload 50MB of files and it fails on files that are less than a meg sometimes.